# What does it mean, "on a three"?

Tags: bad-boys-for-life-2020

Mike calls for help when his partner detective Mike got shot down:

> Mike: Three-fifteen. Shots fired. Officer down. Jose Marti Park. We need Air One **on a three**.

What does it mean, "on a three"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's talking about a "Code 3".  In the US, a [**Code 3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_service_response_codes#United_States) means to respond with lights and sirens.

He's also asking for [**Air One**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPD_Air_Support_Division) backup, which is (as it sounds) support by air in the form of a helicopter.